# What is the range of the function

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

let f:R->R
[image]

What is the range of the function f

I think it is(-infinity to infinity).  But i am confused because p/q is in their lowest term.

Can Someone please help me, Thanks in advance

Comment: It's just $\{\,\tfrac 1n\mid n\in\mathbb N\,\}\cup \{0\}$ as $f(x)$ cannot take any other values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The range is $\{ 0 \} \cup \{ 1/q \mid q \in \mathbb{N} \} \subset [0,1]$ if the sign of $x$ is assigned to $p$.

Otherwise it is $\{ 0 \} \cup \{ 1/q \mid q \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus \{ 0 \} \} \subset [-1,1]$.